# Null entry for parameter 'libraryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PlaceCheckout(Int32, Int32)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm new to MVC. In the view I am trying to send the assetId and the libraryId from the view to the controller however the libraryId is not picking up, I have  tried to find a solution but not having any luck

In the View

```
@using 
(Html.BeginForm("PlaceCheckout", 
"Catalog", FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.AssetId)
 <div>
 Please insert a Library Card ID.
 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LibraryCardId)
 </div>
 div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Check out</button>
 </div>
}
```

Controller Code, LibraryCardId is left out and is set when the user inputs an ID for that card

```
public ActionResult Checkout(int id)
{
 var asset = AssetService.Instance.GetByID(id);

 var model = new CheckoutModel
 {
            AssetId = id,
            ImageUrl = asset.ImageUrl,
            Title = asset.Title,
            LibraryCardId = "",
            IsCheckedOut = CheckOutService.Instance.IsCheckedOut(id)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PlaceCheckout(int assetId, int libraryId)
    {
        CheckOutService.Instance.CheckoutItem(assetId, libraryId);

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = assetId });
    }
```

These are my extension methods

```
public void CheckoutItem(int id, int libraryCardId)
    {
            using( var context = new LibraryContext())
        {
                if (IsCheckedOut(id)) 
                return;

            var item = context.LibraryAssets.Include(a => a.Status).First(a => a.Id == id);

            context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;

            UpdateAssetStatus(id, "Available");

            var now = DateTime.Now;

            var libraryCard = context.LibraryCards.Include(c => c.Checkouts).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == libraryCardId);

            var checkout = new Checkout
            {
                LibraryAsset = item,
                LibraryCard = libraryCard,
                Since = now,
                Until = GetDefaultCheckoutTime(now)
            };

            context.Checkouts.Add(checkout);

            var checkoutHistory = new CheckoutHistory
            {
                CheckedOut = now,
                LibraryAsset = item,
                LibraryCard = libraryCard
            };

            context.CheckoutHistories.Add(checkoutHistory);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: They way the view is PlaceCheckout should be accepting a model not two parameters, try PlaceCheckout(CheckoutModel)

Answer (score 0):

Your view (`@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LibraryCardId)`) is sending LibraryCardId not libraryId and your controller `PlaceCheckout` action is expecting two non-nullable parameters - assetId and libraryId (`public ActionResult PlaceCheckout(int assetId, int libraryId)`). You are getting the exception because libraryId is not supplied.

Please modify your  controller `PlaceCheckout` action to take in LibraryCardId as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceCheckout(int assetId, string libraryCardId )
{
    // This extension method takes int version of libraryCardId
    // So, am really not sure the datatype of libraryCardId
    CheckOutService.Instance.CheckoutItem(assetId, libraryCardId );

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = assetId });
}
```

From the other action `Checkout` that you pasted here, I see that libraryCardId is string. So, have updated data type of second parameter of `PlaceCheckout` action. but your extension method says, libraryCardId is int. So, am really not sure about the data type of libraryCardId. So, please fix it accordingly.